# AngularJS- line breaks within string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, string

So I'm trying to do something very simple and I'm stuck.  I have an text in `ng-bind-html` attribute and within that I wanna set line break so certain part of the text goes to new line.

**What I have tried:**

```
  <div
    ng-repeat="amount in leftAmounts"
    ng-if="$index < 3"
    class="btn-left-lg"
    role="button"
    ng-bind-html="res.strings[amount.type] + '\n' + ': %AMOUNT%' | replaceVariables: {'key':'AMOUNT', 'value': amount.amount, 'type': 'currency', 'currencyCode': transfer.currencyCode}">
  </div>

  <div
    ng-repeat="amount in leftAmounts"
    ng-if="$index < 3"
    class="btn-left-lg"
    role="button"
    ng-bind-html="res.strings[amount.type] + '<br>: %AMOUNT%' | replaceVariables: {'key':'AMOUNT', 'value': amount.amount, 'type': 'currency', 'currencyCode': transfer.currencyCode}">
  </div>
```

I have tried many variations but its just not working. Am I being stupid and missing something very obvious?

I need an line break between `res.strings[amount.type] and  %AMOUNT%`

Any small help would be great

Comment: `\n` is a new line which HTML kind of ignores as whitespace. If you want a newline in HTML use `<br/>` But you already seem to have tried that!

Comment: Please also expand on _"its just not working"_ this is not very concise and doesn't really tell us what _is_ happening.

Comment: Can you provide a sample content for `res.strings[amount.type]` ?